# Differentiable parametrizations of the permutation group

Tags: permutations, lie-groups

Typically the permutation group is considered a discrete operation, but I wonder if there is a way to parametrize it with a larger group such that one gets intermediate continuous transformations between the discrete permutations, and such that the permutation groups are proper subgroups

Comment: This is unclear as it stands.  Are you looking for a transformation group that contains a copy of $S_n$ as a subgroup?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an injective homomorphism $S_n \to O(n)$: Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, \ldots e_n \}$ of $\mathbb R^n$.  Then for a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, consider the linear map that sends the basis vector $e_i$ to $e_{\sigma(i)}$.  Convince yourself that this is an orthogonal transformation, $T_\sigma \in O(n)$.  Then convince yourself that $\sigma \mapsto T_\sigma$ is a homomorphism.  So this exhibits $S_n$ as a discrete subgroup of $O(n)$.

Observe also that $\det T_\sigma = \text{sgn}(\sigma)$, so the alternating subgroup $A_n \le S_n$ is mapped into $SO(n)$.

I suppose this allows you to think of general orthogonal transformations as some sort of 'intermediate continuous transformations' between the permutations.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a 'parametrization' of the permutation group, but I hope it's in the spirit of what you were looking for.

Comment: this works, thanks!